# How was this equation factored?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

I'm really confused as to how $\frac 21(x^2-3x+\frac 94)$ was factored into $\frac 21(x-\frac 32)^2$.

If possible, explain it to me like I'm five.

I also don't quite get how $(x^2) = (x)^2$ is the same thing. What if $x$ is a negative?

Comment: Write as $4x^2-12x + 9 = 4x^2-6x-6x+9 = 2x(2x-3) -3x(2x-3) = (2x-3)^2$ and that divided by $4$.

Comment: Alternatively use $(2x)^2 - 2\cdot(2x)\cdot(3) + (3)^2 = (2x-3)^2$

Comment: I think you got confused with $x^2$,
 $x^2$ means square the $x$, that is if $x = -1$ it gives $(-1)^2 = 1$.

Comment: `What if x is a negative?` What would the problem be there?

Comment: Well $-x^2$ = negative $x$ while $(-x)^2$ = positive $x$?

Comment: @user472288 Careful with the parenthesis. If you take $\,(x^2) = (x)^2\,$ and substitute $\,x=-a\,$ then you get $\,\big((-a)^2\big) = \big((-a)\big)^2\,$. Both are positive and, in fact, equal.

Comment: () are place holders.  They mean to treat everything in them as "blocks".  $(5) = 5 = ((5))$.  So $(x)^2 = x^2 = (x^2)$.   If $x = -2$ then $x^2 = (x)^2 = (x^2)$ are all the same thing "negative 2 squared".  There is one catch.  We can NOT write "negative 2 squared" as $-2^2$  That is NOT $-2\times -2$.  That is "2 squared made negative".  Because the $-$ in $-2^2$ is "attached to $2^2$ and NOT to the $2$ if we want to write "negative 2 squared" we *must* use () and write $(-2)^2$.

Comment: $-x^2 \ne (-x)^2$ but   $-x^2 = -(x^2)$

Comment: This is like $-2 + 5 = 3$ but $-(2+5) = -(7) = -7$.  So $-x^2 = -x*x = -(x*x) = -x^2$ but $(-x)^2 = (-x)*(-x) = x*x = x^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two expressions are: $2(x^2 - 3x + 9/4)$ and $2(x - 3/2)^2$. Since each expression is written as the product of $2$ and a parenthetical expression, it will suffice to show the parenthetical expressions are equal. In other words, let us show that: $x^2 - 3x + 9/4 = (x - 3/2)^2$.

To do so, we will expand $(x - 3/2)^2$ using the distributive property to see if we get $x^2 - 3x + 9/4$.

Here we go:

$$(x - 3/2)(x - 3/2) = (x - 3/2)x + (x - 3/2)(-3/2) = (x^2 - 3x/2) + (-3x/2 + 9/4)$$

The final two expressions can be combined because there are like terms:

$$x^2 - 3x/2 -3x/2 + 9/4 = x^2 - 6x/2 + 9/4 = x^2 - 3x + 9/4$$

just as we hoped, wished, and desired. This establishes that the two parenthetical expressions are, indeed, equal; so, the two expressions multiplied by $2$ are equal, as well.

Comment: Hey Ben, thanks alot (if I could pick 2 best answers, I would as I'm pretty torn between the two ^^)

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2-3x+\frac94=x^2+2\cdot\Big(-\frac32\Big)\cdot x+\Big(-\frac32\Big)^2=\Big(x-\frac32\Big)^2$$

Answer (score 0):

It is important to realize that $(a + b)^2$ DOES !!!!!!NOT!!!!!! equal $a^2 + b^2$ so you wouldn't expect $(x - \frac 32)^2$ to equal $x^2 + \frac 94$.  Something extra must *APPEAR*.

$(a + b)^2 = (a+b)(a+b) = a(a+b) + b(a + b) = (a*a + a*b)+(b*a + b*b)= a*a + (a*b + b*a) + b*b = a^2 + 2ab +b^2$.

So if you do $(a+b)^2 \implies a^2 + b^2 + SOMETHING $ the $SOMeTHING = 2ab$ must appear (out of nowhere).

So if you go the other way $a^2 + 2ab +b^2= (a+b)^2$ the $2ab$ *must* "disappear.

....

Okay?

So.  Remember this $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$.

Do $(a+b)^2 = (a+b)(a+b) = a(a+b) + b(a+b) = a^2 +(ab + ab) + b^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$ enough times untill you *absolutely* convince yourself it is true.

Okay.

So How do we do something like $(x^2 - 3x + \frac 9/2) = (x \pm something) \pm something else?$.

Well we want $x^2 - 3x + \frac 94 = (x + a)^2= x^2 +2ax + a^2$

And we *know*  $(x \pm a)^2 = x^2 \pm 2ax + a^2$.

So we need to set $x^2 = x^2$.

$-3x = 2ax$

$a^2= \frac  94 $

$-3x = 2ax \implies 2a = -3 \implies a=-\frac 32$.

And we also have $a^2 = \frac 94$ so $a =\pm 32$.

So we have $(x - \frac 32)^2 = x^2 -2*\frac 32 x + (\frac 32)^2$

$= x^2 - 3x + \frac 94$.

Comment: Thank you fleablood, this, embarrassingly, was exactly what I needed.